# pointing my blogger domain to my own webhost

Tags: dns, cross-domain, web-hosting, blogger

I just purchased a domain for my blogger blog through google(goDaddy)
Currently, it is pointed to blogger web host.

I'd like to point it to my own web host as well, so i can host files, while not losing my blog stuffs from blogger.

Is this possible? for a domain to have 2 web host?

I'm sorry, i'm really new to these domain and hosting, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your domain on your site and then setup a subdomain-- like blog.YOURDOMAIN.COM-- and point that to your blogger account.

1. Go to http://www.google.com/a/domainname, replacing domainname with your domain name.
2. Now you will need to login to your Google account utilizing a username and password you previously created specifically for Google Apps for your domain. If you do not know this information, click 'Can't access your account.'
3. Once logged in, click the 'Domain Settings' tab.
4. Click on "Advanced DNS Settings".
5. You will now see listed your Sign-In Name, Password, and PIN.
6. Click Sign-In to DNS Console and use the Sign-In Name and Password to login.
7. You should now be in the Domain Control Center.  Click Forward, and then select Forward Subdomain.
8. In the Add subdomain field, enter the subdomain.
9. Select http:// or https:// depending on your server settings.
10. In Forward this subdomain to, enter the URL you want to forward the subdomain to.  This will be the URL for your Blogger blog.
11. To view additional options, click Advanced Options, and then select one of the following:

    Forward Only — Specifies the length of time for this forwarding setting. Select one of the following redirect types:
        I am permanently forwarding my domain — Redirects to the site you specified in the Forward To field using a "301 Moved Permanently" HTTP response. The HTTP 301 response code tells user-agents (including search engines) the location has permanently moved.
        I am only temporarily forwarding my domain — Redirects to the site you specified in the Forward To field using a "302 Found" HTTP response. The HTTP 302 response code tells user-agents (including search engines) that the location has temporarily moved.
    Forward with Masking
    Title — Displays at the top of the browser window and in search results.
    Description — A short description of your website to display in search engine results.
    Keyword — A list of comma-separated keywords that describe the content and purpose of your website.
12. Click OK.

The main domain you just continue to point to the IP of your web host.

Comment: thanks alot mike, now that i created my subdomain. how do i point it to my webhost? is therea subdomain manager?

Comment: You for forward subdomains as well.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4040?locale=en